# Empty white space at the end of document after $.slideUp()

Tags: jquery, css

I have images content that I slide down and up in order to show/hide the pictures. The slide toggle works perfectly and the page stretches to the content, then goes back to normal when I slide it back up.

Unless, I scroll a bit in any direction before sliding back up. Even if I scroll one pixel up or down, sliding up the images to hide them will leave an empty white space at the bottom of the document.

I set a border around *body* or *html* to see if they had a weird size, but they resize correctly so they are not the problem.

My *html* and *body* tags don't have any margin or padding, and everything displays correctly. It seems like the DOCUMENT is the problem. for example, here are console outputs before slideToggle:

```
$('body').height() -> 2855.578125
$('html').height() -> 2984.375
$(document).height() -> 2984
```

Then here are the values after sliding back the images:

```
$('body').height() -> 2855.578125
$('html').height() -> 2984.375
$(document).height() -> 5957
```

As you can see, the *body* and *html* tags have resized back to their original value. Only the document seems corrupted. I noticed that if I use the console to hide the overflow of *html* then set it back to auto, it resets the height and fixes the problem but the page jerks around for a bit.

I don't really have any ideas anymore. I searched Google and SO extensively, many people have similar problems but nobody has the same exact strange bug. If someone knows how to reset the height to recalculate automatically, that would be ok. Don't really care about trying to figure out what's wrong anymore, just want to get rid of this white space.

Comment: could you put demo, to see in action

Comment: You could try setting the 3 heights in variables and then when the body and html return to normal, set the document height.

I know it's ugly but it should solve your immediate problem.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón I thought about it yep, however I'm not sure about posting the URL here. I will see if I can reproduce it on jsfiddle :)

Comment: @Difster Yep, thought about it, however there are multiple accordions that can slide up and down, all with different heights so I can't do that..

Comment: That's unfortunate. Could it be that there's something your css that's interfering?

Comment: That's possible yes.. But I don't see what it is. I can't reproduce the behavior on jsfiddle, I'm sorry guys I know I'm asking a lot without being able to provide much details. I will see if someone has an idea and if not I'll just delete the question as I can't provide more info